# Avoiding the "synchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated" error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load an HTML file and insert it into a DIV tag in my HTML. I've tried everything I can think of but still getting that ynchronous XMLHttpRequest is deprecated error. There is plenty of this question here but nothing I did seemed to work. My last effort was to create a worker. Like this:

Here is the worker:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log("got the message");
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', e.data);
    client.onreadystatechange = function () {
        self.postMessage(client.responseText);
    }
    client.send();
}, false);
```

Here is the code in the main HTML:

```
function doit() {
            var worker = new Worker('doWork.js');

            worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
                console.log(e.data);
                //$("#content").clear();
                $("#content").append(e.data);
            }, false);

            worker.postMessage(theURL); // Send data to our worker.
}
```

But still getting the same error. Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `client.open('GET', e.data, true);`? It should default to that but it's the first thing I would try.

Comment: Exactly which line is producing the error? The code you provided generates an asynchronous request, not a synchronous one.

Comment: This doesn't look like it should produce this error. I would check (1) that this code is really causing the error, and not some other code or library you're using, and (2) this code is really *running* -- i.e., you are not accidentally editing a different file than the one you have loaded in your browser. Failing any leads those tests, I would check (3) that your `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` and `send` have not been altered by a library.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.

Comment: Thanks all. The exact code producing the error is this: $("#content").append(e.data);